# Lines in output to JSON format, else not working

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to convert time statistics from one of our scripts to JSON format for further processing, but have failed to do so. Here's an example of what the statistics output looks like:

```
cmd ls -lah
0m1.964s
cmd echo something
0m4.183s
cmd setup-environment
0m0.401s
```

I would like to have the line starting with "cmd" as the key, and the time value in the next line as "value".

I can get "cmd" as key name and the actual command as cmd.value but that is not exactly what I'm aiming for:

```
cat statistics.txt | jq -R 'split("\n") - [""]' | jq '.[] | if select( contains("cmd")) then { "cmd": . } else { "time": . } end'
```

I also know that "if" and "select" can mean pretty much the same thing with jq, but I don't know how else I could achieve what I want ("else" doesn't even produce anything in my example). This is what I get currently:

```
{
  "cmd": "cmd ls -lah"
}
{
  "cmd": "cmd echo something"
}
{
  "cmd": "cmd setup-environment"
}
```

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All-jq solution:

```
jq -Rn '{ (inputs): input }' statistics.txt
```

The command-line options are:

- -R for raw input
- -n so that the `inputs` filter sees the first line

#### {"cmd": _, "value": _}

It might make more sense to produce JSON objects with more structure, e.g. of the form `{"cmd": _, "value": _}`.  Assuming the "cmd" line always begins as in statistics.txt, this can also easily be achieved, e.g. by:

```
jq -Rn '{ cmd: inputs[4:], value: input }' statistics.txt
```

#### If your jq does not have `inputs`

```
jq -R -s 'split("\n")
| recurse( .[2:] | select(length>0))
| {(.[0]): .[1]}' statistics.txt
```

Comment: So elegant! I'll use the second example as suggested, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**`jq`** + **`paste`** solution:

```
jq -R 'split(",") | {(.[0]) : .[1]}' <(paste -d, - - <statistics.txt)
```

The output:

```
{
  "cmd ls -lah": "0m1.964s"
}
{
  "cmd echo something": "0m4.183s"
}
{
  "cmd setup-environment": "0m0.401s"
}
```

Comment: This fragile approach is made even more fragile by using "," as the separator character. Using '\t' instead might be better  ...

Comment: @peak, No, as it's just a text file it could also contain tab characters as well as a comma. So it's not "better". The OP may find the optimal delimiter considering his own internal rules

Answer (score -1):

How about combining shell variables and [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)?

You can do something like this in a bash script:

```
cmd="cmd ls -lah"
cat << EOF
{
  \"cmd\": \"$cmd\",
  \"time\": \"$(time $cmd)\"
}
EOF
```

If you don't like the output of `time` or other commands, you can enclose it in a shell function.

```
chrono() {
   command=$1
   result=$(/bin/time $command >/dev/null 2>&1)
   # Awk or sed to give format to the output 
}
```